# Finding $k$ such that two quadratics share exactly one root

Tags: analysis, polynomials

> For what values of $k$ do the quadratics $x^2+kx+1$ and $kx^2+x+1$ share exactly one root?

If we let $r$ be the shared root we get

$r^2+kr+1=0$ and $kr^2+r+1=0$.

From here we have

$r^2+kr+1 = kr^2+r+1$ $\Rightarrow$ $r^2(1-k)+r(k-1)=0$

Here on my idea was to use the discriminant so find $k$ such that the equation has only one root. This is what I got

$(k-1)^2-4(1-k)(0)=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $(k-1)^2 = 0$ and therefore $k=1$.

This seems to be wrong since the correct answer was that $k$ should equal $-2$. Why isn't my approach working?

Comment: You should solve the system. Expess $k$ from both equations

Comment: Both equations have two roots, of which one is common. You are combining them to a third equation, and nothing mandates that it has a double root.

Comment: But am I not essentially using the discriminant on the system to find $k$ such that it has only one root?

Comment: That was for@Aqua.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ah I understand.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

There is an $x$ such that

$$x^2+kx+1=kx^2+x+1=0.$$

Let us eliminate $x$ from this system. We multiply the first by $k$ and subtract the second, giving

$$(k^2-1)x+k-1=0$$ and

$$x=-\frac1{k+1}.$$

Substitute in one of the equations and solve for $k$. Then for every solution in $k$, check that the other roots are distinct.

---

As noted by @CalvinLin, we still have to check the compatibility of the equations in case $k=\pm1$ as these create singular cases in the above analysis.

With $k=1$, the two polynomials coincide, and with $k=-1$,
$$x^2-x+1=-x^2+x+1=0$$ is impossible.

Comment: As an aside, you have to check the $k=\pm 1$ case separately as you risk dividing by 0.

Comment: @CalvinLin: quite right, thanks.